# THREAD 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT CALayer removeAllAnimations message sent to deallocated

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nszombie

There are a lot of question with the same title but somehow I felt that every case is different as my problem is still not resolved and I've no clue why and also there are not enough solutions for Swift. So here is my scenerio:

I've used [CarbonKit](https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit) to show 4 view controllers in a single view controller. The `FourthViewController` sends a get call using [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). It successfully loads the data and reload `tableView`. However when I drag this table view my app crashes and I get `EXC_BREAKPOINT` and sometimes `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` for the same thing.

Here is what I've tried:

1. Upon searching I came to know about zombies. So I enabled it and when the app gives me EXC I get this:

> -[CALayer removeAllAnimations]: message sent to deallocated instance

So as I checked there was no animation I might have been using in this class. But considering it's inside CarbonKit they might have something to do with it but I'm unable to figure it out.

2. I run **Product > Analyze** from xCode and the most of the blue icons are on FBSDK which have nothing to do with this class so it was not useful to debug at all.

Here are the screenshots:
[image: EXC_BREAKPOINT] and [image: EXC_BAD_ACCESS]
and here is what Instruments 9.0 zombies message gave me:
[image: Zombie Message] and [image: More Detailed Zombie]

I get this in console of xCode:
[image]
If you need more information I'll update my questions.

**UPDATE**
Here is my code when I'm getting the data from web using Alamofire. Now this call runs successfully and I can scroll down to view all the data that is loaded in the table. But when i scroll up then it crashes with the above errors.

```
let headers = [
            "security-token": "MY_SECURITY_CODE_HERE",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]

        let url = "URL_GOES_HERE"
        //print(url)
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

            if let result = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if result["status"] as! Int == 0
                    {
                        self.clearAllNotice()
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error",
                                                      message: "\(result["msg"] ?? "Our Server is not responding at the moment. Try again later!" as AnyObject)",
                            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                                         style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.clearAllNotice()

                        for docReviewDict in (result["data"] as! [AnyObject]) {

                            let docReview = DoctorReview(dict: docReviewDict as! [String : AnyObject])
                            self.mainDoctorReviewsArray.append(docReview)
                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.clearAllNotice()
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Something is wrong",
                                                  message: error.localizedDescription,
                                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                                     style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                }
            } else {
              print("Somethins is wrong with the URL")
            }
        }
```

Just in case here is the cell which is loaded in the tableview.
[image]

**Latest:**

Based on the comment I've done this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
```

but still the same result I'am getting

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb4c4beb8)

on `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReviewCell") as! ReviewsTableViewCell` line when I drag down on table view.

**IMPLEMENTATION OF CELL**

The class name is `ReviewsViewController` which has a `@IBOutlet fileprivate var tableView: UITableView!`.

Then in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Then I've table view delegate and datasource:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return mainDoctorReviewsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReviewCell") as! ReviewsTableViewCell //WHEN THE APP IS CRASHED AS I DRAG THE TABLE VIEW IT CRASH ON THIS LINE. As this line is highlighted in red with message "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x186ddd61c)"

        cell.userPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userPhoto.frame.width / 2;
        cell.userPhoto.layer.masksToBounds = true

        cell.userName.text = mainDoctorReviewsArray[indexPath.row].name

        cell.starRating.settings.fillMode = .precise

        if let rate = mainDoctorReviewsArray[indexPath.row].rating
        {
            cell.starRating.rating = Double(rate)!
        }
        else {
            cell.starRating.rating = 0
        }

        cell.desc.text = mainDoctorReviewsArray[indexPath.row].feedback
        cell.dateOfReview.text = mainDoctorReviewsArray[indexPath.row].dates
        cell.timeOfReview.text = mainDoctorReviewsArray[indexPath.row].times

        return cell
    }
```

and in the cell class there is just:

```
import UIKit
import Cosmos

class ReviewsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var timeOfReview: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var dateOfReview: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var desc: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var starRating: CosmosView!
    @IBOutlet var userName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var userPhoto: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

The screenshot of `tableView` is above in this question.

This is the parent class under which 4 ViewControllers loads: [dropbox.com/s/d5sh4ej1ssv6873/…](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5sh4ej1ssv6873/DoctorDetailsViewController.swift?dl=0) And this is the class which has the tableview is and on scroll it crashed the app: [dropbox.com/s/3kiju9hn3uewzar/ReviewsViewController.swift?dl‌​=0](http://dropbox.com/s/3kiju9hn3uewzar/ReviewsViewController.swift?dl%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B=0)

Comment: Check if you have used assign instead of strong/weak as access specifier for any of your property. It may result in zombies.

Comment: @PuneetSharma not in my code but as I'm searching `assign` I get this in many of the pods which I've installed.

Comment: It could be an UI related task which is not performed on the main thread.

Comment: could you post the code for the call via Alamofire?

Comment: @user3581248 please see the updated portion of my question.

Comment: My suggestion would be run some `malloc_history` debugging, most possible cause should be `assign` or `removeFromSuperlayer` mis-usage.

Comment: dispatch main queue to reload table view.

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar bu putting table view inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` I'm getting the same error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. You can see more in latest section in the question.

Comment: have you deleted any label but not removed IBOutlet?

Comment: If it is possible provide me your storyboard and ViewController class

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar it's a table view with a custom cell. It displays the data correctly. if there are lets say 2 rows the program won't crash. But if there are more rows and there is a need to drag and see them then the crash happens.

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar sure... so do you want all 5 classes? As I'm using CarbonKit and this view is just one of the 4 views showing in the tabs.

Comment: yes please provide all related code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159050/discussion-between-chaudhry-talha-and-dattatray-deokar).

Comment: Can you post the implementation of your cell?

Comment: @SanthoshR updated my question. All the code is under `IMPLEMENTATION OF CELL` section.

Comment: is this showing for first reload of you tableView?

Comment: @PramodKumarSaxena yes as it get crash when I scroll down table view.

Comment: can you please re-check that your table view cell `ReviewsTableViewCell` have the same identifier as `ReviewCell`? In your Storyboard.

Comment: @PramodKumarSaxena Just checked again it's the same `ReviewCell` identifier in code and in attributes inspector. The crash only occurred when I start scrolling tableview.

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha Try using clear your drivedData by quitting the Xcode and again run it.

Comment: dequeue the cell as such: 

  var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier)
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier)
  }

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned above it probably is related with working with ui objects not from main thread.
If your using xCode 9 you should see as a runtime warning. (You can set checkmark in EditScheme->Diagnostics->MainThreadChecker->pause on issues).

Also you can override dealloc method of you ReviewsTableViewCell and add some logs\asserts to check if it's called from main thread.

Usually it happens if you pass your view\cell to some block, and you will have this crash on releasing this object when exiting from block.

Comment: I got this: `Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 11684, TID: 3261572, Thread name: com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit` when it is on the first tab.

Comment: [UIApplication applicationState] is not the problem.

Comment: This is what I got when as I turned the pause on issues on. Other that that I get the issues mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna make some small suggestions to clean up your code. Not sure if it will solve the problem but it will help to ensure that your issue isn't based on something trivial.

1. I'm not sure where you're calling it, but in the request load completion handler make sure to capture `self` weakly.

   `Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { [weak self] response in`

   This way you're not forcing the object to stay alive until the loading finishes, which may cause it to load in the wrong place.
2. Make sure that the completion block (mentioned above) is running on the main thread. You're making calls to UI, so just check it to be safe.
3. Your IB outlets should be declared as `@IBOutlet weak var foo: UIView?` You might be causing yourself problems by strongly referencing the views.
4. `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:)` can return `nil`. You should be using `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)` - and don't forget to register the cell using `register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)` first.

Comment: Got the same error: `[CALayer removeAllAnimations]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1c103e240` and `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x186ddd61c)` on the line mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the cell class type?

If not add in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.register(ReviewsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReviewCell")
```

Next just dequeue it in cellForRow:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellFor(identifier: "ReviewCell", indexPath: indexPath) as! ReviewsTableViewCell
```

Check if the error is still happening

Comment: Do I need to do this as the cell is not in a separate .xib

Comment: are you asking or saying? hehe. Yes you need to register ReviewCell.

Comment: just making sure... As what I know is that if I have a prototype cell in table view I don't need to register it. But if I have the cell on separate .xib then I need to register it.

Comment: Ah allright didn´t realise that you connected a prototype cell. Then you don´t need to register it. Did you set the identifier name of the cell with "ReviewCell" ?

Comment: yup that I've check thrice :D

Comment: I've provided the code in dropbox you can also download and see if you can find the problem.

Comment: Can you add the VC where the tableView is declared?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5sh4ej1ssv6873/DoctorDetailsViewController.swift?dl=0 this is the view the four VC's are declared.

Comment: Yes but in which one of these 5 VC´s there is the table where the crash happens when you scroll up?

Comment: In `ReviewsViewController`'s tableView. This class can be downloaded from http://dropbox.com/s/3kiju9hn3uewzar/ReviewsViewController.swift?dl%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B=0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened when I executed this (`myView` is a subview on a cell)

```swift
myView.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
```

I don't find anything removing a layer from your code but if you did it outside of that, then I think that's the problem.